# Android SDK: Linear Layout won't wrap text vertically

Tags: android, xml, sdk

I'm having an issue with not being able to have the linear layout wrap to the content vertically. I've tried manipulating many of the different layouts and buttons and switching them to wrap content, but I've had no luck.

Here's my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
</EditText>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </LinearLayout>
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="RadioButton"
     />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    />
```

Here is what the UI looks like:
![What the UI currently looks like] https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xv4tE.png

What I want it to look like:
![What I want it to look like] https://i.stack.imgur.com/1V2E1.png
I had to manually drag it and specify the pixels, something I don't want to be in the final app.

Comment: Maybe the answer lies in your background drawable? In Android Studio preview your layout file looks fine without the background attributes. http://i.imgur.com/PPxvqv6.png

Comment: That was it damien. I had copied the first Linear Layout to the second and forgot to remove the @drawable/background, causing it to wrap to the size of the background. Thanks!

Comment: Good, you can probably accept Rayyan's answer as this is essentially what s/he did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Try this Code:
```

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="RadioButton" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Answer (score 0):

looking at the pictures I understand that you want to position the button and the radiobutton at the bottom right? In that case, you're root layout is supposed to be a relativeLayout and the RadioButton and the Button must be enclosed by a LinearLayout with the property alignParentBottom="true"